# On App update custom plist file will get updated or do we need to do some thing?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, app-store, plist

I have an app in appstore now im going to push out an update of app, Im having a custom Plist file with set of values in my application bundle, and these values are been modified from the version which is in production and in addition even more key value pairs are added in to this file.

Now my doubt is on updating this app to appStore **will the update process automatically overrides(updates) my new plist file on top of existing one** or do we need to do some work around like how we do for database changes like coredata migration and all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the update is deployed it will overwrite existing plist files.

Answer (score 2):

As explained here: [iOS App Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/PerformanceTips/PerformanceTips.html), this is what happens when you update an app:

> **Files Saved During App Updates**
>
> When a user downloads an app update,
> iTunes installs the update in a new app directory. It then moves the
> user’s data files from the old installation over to the new app
> directory before deleting the old installation. Files in the following
> directories are guaranteed to be preserved during the update process:
>
> - Application_Home/Documents
> - Application_Home/Library
>
> Although files
> in other user directories may also be moved over, you should not rely
> on them being present after an update.

This means that all the resources that were in your bundle will be "lost" and you will have the new ones from your new bundle. If you were using this plist file for read only purposes this won't be a problem, if you were saving some user preference on this file, i'm afraid that these user information will be lost. You should save this kind of data in the documents directory, always!

Answer (score 0):

When you update your app on App store it replaces new binary with old binary. So with binary it also replaces your plist too. So don't worry about that, just be aware that your info in app store details and details in plist should be same otherwise it will not take your binary file for app version update.